# ffmpeg make fate --make: *** [fate-filter-fps-cfr] crc Error 1 - I haven't changed any code

Tags: linux, memory, ffmpeg, fedora

```
ENV:Linux SZV1000266228 3.0.76-0.11-default #1 SMP Fri Jun 14 08:21:43 UTC 2013 (ccab990) x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

ffmpeg version N-104708-g8a18db3 Copyright (c) 2000-2021 the FFmpeg developers

  built with gcc 7 (GCC)

  configuration: --enable-gpl --disable-x86asm -samples=/usr1/wujian/ffmpeg_master/fate-suite

  libavutil      57.  9.101 / 57.  9.101

  libavcodec     59. 14.100 / 59. 14.100

  libavformat    59.  9.102 / 59.  9.102

  libavdevice    59.  0.101 / 59.  0.101

  libavfilter     8. 17.100 /  8. 17.100

  libswscale      6.  1.101 /  6.  1.101

  libswresample   4.  0.100 /  4.  0.100

  libpostproc    56.  0.100 / 56.  0.100
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from '/usr1/wujian/ffmpeg_master/fate-suite/qtrle/apple-animation-variable-fps-bug.mov':

TEST    filter-fps-cfr
--- /usr1/wujian/ffmpeg_master/ffmpeg/tests/ref/fate/filter-fps-cfr     2021-11-24 17:53:53.000000000 +0800

+++ tests/data/fate/filter-fps-cfr      2021-11-30 15:01:04.000000000 +0800

@@ -3,91 +3,91 @@

 #codec_id 0: rawvideo

 #dimensions 0: 112x182

 #sar 0: 0/1

-0,          0,          0,        1,    30576, 0xcdc29b3d

-0,          1,          1,        1,    30576, 0xcdc29b3d

-0,          2,          2,        1,    30576, 0xcdc29b3d

-0,          3,          3,        1,    30576, 0xcdc29b3d

-0,          4,          4,        1,    30576, 0xcdc29b3d

-0,          5,          5,        1,    30576, 0xcdc29b3d

-0,          6,          6,        1,    30576, 0x5c83656c

-0,          7,          7,        1,    30576, 0x5c83656c

-0,          8,          8,        1,    30576, 0x5c83656c

-0,          9,          9,        1,    30576, 0x5c83656c

-0,         10,         10,        1,    30576, 0x5c83656c

-0,         11,         11,        1,    30576, 0x5c83656c

-0,         12,         12,        1,    30576, 0x5c83656c

-0,         13,         13,        1,    30576, 0x26b67f83

-0,         14,         14,        1,    30576, 0x26b67f83

+0,          0,          0,        1,    30576, 0x7b6c65df

+0,          1,          1,        1,    30576, 0x7b6c65df

+0,          2,          2,        1,    30576, 0x7b6c65df

+0,          3,          3,        1,    30576, 0x7b6c65df

+0,          4,          4,        1,    30576, 0x7b6c65df

+0,          5,          5,        1,    30576, 0x7b6c65df

+0,          6,          6,        1,    30576, 0x0a2d300e

+0,          7,          7,        1,    30576, 0x0a2d300e

+0,          8,          8,        1,    30576, 0x0a2d300e

+0,          9,          9,        1,    30576, 0x0a2d300e

+0,         10,         10,        1,    30576, 0x0a2d300e

+0,         11,         11,        1,    30576, 0x0a2d300e

+0,         12,         12,        1,    30576, 0x0a2d300e

+0,         13,         13,        1,    30576, 0xd4514a25

+0,         14,         14,        1,    30576, 0xd4514a25

Test filter-fps-cfr failed. Look at tests/data/fate/filter-fps-cfr.err for details.
make: *** [fate-filter-fps-cfr] Error 1
```

I found out it was the crc that failed，The code is as follows:

```
uint32_t crc = av_adler32_update(0, pkt->data, pkt->size);
```

I'm confused now, thank you for your answers.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Analysis: Yasm is an assembly compiler. To improve efficiency, ffmpeg uses assembly instructions, such as MMX and SSE. Therefore, if yasm is not installed in the system, the preceding error is reported.
Fix the error: Install the yasm compiler.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Analysis: Yasm is an assembly compiler. To improve efficiency, ffmpeg uses assembly instructions, such as MMX and SSE. Therefore, if yasm is not installed in the system, the preceding error is reported.
Fix the error: Install the yasm compiler.